# JavaScript syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, formula, puzzle

I'm doing "fifteen puzzle" game. I'm only a beginner, so I chose this project to implement. My problem is shuffle algorithm :

```
function shuffle() {

    $('td').empty();
    var p = 0;
    var f = 0;

    do {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
        var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        if ($('#' + rand).is(':empty')) {
            p = p + 1;
            document.getElementById(rand).textContent = p
            var f = $('td').not(":empty").length;
        } else {}
    } while (f < 15)
```

That works cool, but I've heard that almost 50% of all random shuffle like mine is unsolvable. So I found [math formula at wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8) for this game, explaining how you can avoid that.

Here's modified algorithm that doesn't work either. The way I know it is `alert` stuff: it launches only 2 times instead of 31.

```
array = [];

function algorithm (){
   // alert('works')
    for (var c=16; c<17; c++){
        document.getElementById(c).textContent = '100';
    }     

    for (var i=1; i<16; i++){ 
        var curId = document.getElementById(i).id;
        var curIdNum = Math.floor(curId);
        alert('works')
        var curIn = document.getElementById(i).textContent;
        var curInNum = Math.floor(curIn);
        array.push(i);
array[i] = new Array();
        for (var j=1; j<15; j++){
            var nextId = curIdNum + j; //curIdNum NOT cerIdNum
            var nextIn = document.getElementById(nextId).textContent;
        //alert('works')
        if (nextId < 16){
            var nextInNum = Math.floor(nextIn);
            if (curInNum > nextInNum){
                array[i].push(j) 
            }
        }
    }            

    var sum = 0; 
    for (var a=0; a<15; a++){
        var add = array[a].length;
        sum = sum + add;
    }            
    var end = sum + 4;
    if (end % 2 == 0){
        document.getElementById('16').textContent = "";
    }            
    else {       
        shuffle();
    }            
}                
}
```

### The question is the same:

What's wrong? Two-dimensional array doesn't work.If you've got any questions - ask.

Just to make it clear: 2 `for` loops with `i` and `j` should make a 2-dimensional array like this `[ this is " var i" -->[1,3,4,5,7], this is "var i" too-->[5,7,9,14,15]]`. Inside each `i` there's `j`. The `for` loop with `var a` should count the number of `j`s inside each `i`. if the number of `j`s is even, the code is finished and shuffle's accomplished, otherwise shuffle should be made once again.

Comment: What's the value of `f` when the `while` statement is first encountered? If it's undefined, then `f < 15` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Another point - you are defining the function **algorithm** over and over again within the for loop. Do you really need it that way? You are better off defining it once, outside of the while loop  and calling it within the while loop

Comment: @TedHopp, I actually made the whole thing exactly the way it's written here, so `var f;` - that's it. But the `do` part works perfect. Doesn't that mean, that `while` statement works as well?

Comment: @GoodMove - With the `do..while()` statement, the body of the loop is executed once before the test condition is evaluated. This gives the body of the loop a chance to set `f` before the condition is evaluated. With a `while(){...}` loop, the condition is evaluated before the body is evaluated even once. You need to initialize `f` properly before the `while` statement if you want to use a `while` loop instead of a `do..while` loop.

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande @TedHopp I tried to do this way, but it didn't work. when I remove all the variables in `for` loops and just make a two-dimensional array and then alert it - array's the way it must be. When I return the variables back and alert the array again, `for` loop goes 2 or 3 times instead of 15. What the hell?

Comment: You haven't defined f. If you define f within the loop, then use a `do..while` statement. At the end of the loop, put a `console.log(f)` statement, and paste the output here.

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with your html code as well...[I got this far...](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/KUBLA/), please note that if you can post this I'd be happy to help and show conversion to jQuery

Comment: @abc123 Here's the link to the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/KUBLA/2/

Comment: @YetAnotherUser after defining `f = 0` and adding `alert(f)` in `while {}` alert box pops up with '15' in it. I think everything's OK with `do/while` part. There are mistakes in my `algorithm()` function I guess, which I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var nextId = cerIdNum + j;
```

in that fiddle, I don't see this `cerIdNum` declared & defined neither as local nor as global variable, I suppose that is `curIdNum`

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake. But after replacing it for `curIdNum`, alert box pops up 6 times instead of 31. That means that something is still wrong.

Comment: I think the issue is with the `j` loop inside the `i` loop

Comment: @GoodMove please refer to the code in my post - I have resolved the problems and also have placed comments next to the lines that have been corrected

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below definition of `algorithm` and let us know if this works. Basically, the alert messages would come only twice, since there were usages of undefined variables. For the purpose of illustration, I have placed comments at where the problem points occured. Due to these problems, your script would stop executing abruptly thereby resulting in the behavior you described.

Oh and by the way - I did not have time to go through the Wiki link provided - hence you will have to verify your logic is correct. However, I have definitely resolved the errors causing the behavior you observed.

As an aside - consider using jQuery, your code will be a lot cleaner...

```
function algorithm (){
       // alert('works')
        for (var c=16; c<17; c++){
            document.getElementById(c).textContent = '100';
        }     

        for (var i=1; i<16; i++){
            var curId = document.getElementById(i).id;
            var curIdNum = Math.floor(curId);
            alert('works')
            var curIn = document.getElementById(i).textContent;
            var curInNum = Math.floor(curIn);
            array.push(i);
            for (var j=1; j<15; j++){
                var nextId = curIdNum + j; //curIdNum NOT cerIdNum
                var nextIn = document.getElementById(nextId).textContent;
            //alert('works')
            if (nextId < 16){
                var nextInNum = Math.floor(nextIn);
                if (curInNum > nextInNum){
                    array.push(j) //array[i].push does not make sense
                }
            }
        }            

        var sum = 0; 
        for (var a=0; a<15; a++){
            var add = array.length; //array[1].length does not make sense
            sum = sum + add;
        }            
        var end = sum + 4;
        if (end % 2 == 0){
            document.getElementById('16').textContent = "";
        }            
        else {       
            shuffle();
        }            
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but the `for` loop with `var i` in this code works 4-10 times instead of 15. I have no idea why. And I found a REAL mistake in my code: I forgot about `array[i] = new Array()` to make two-dimensional array. That's why `array[i].push(j)` and `array[a].length` didn't make sense to you.

Comment: @GoodMove Great.. that's why I wrote explicitly in my response that you would need to verify the logic for the shuffle :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by totally rewriting the code. Thank everyone for help!

Here's what do work:

```
function shuffle (){
press = 1;
$('td').empty().removeClass();
p=0;
var f;

do {
    var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    var rand=arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
        if ($('#'+ rand).is(':empty')){
            p = p + 1;
            document.getElementById(rand).textContent = p
            var f = $('td').not(":empty").length;
        }
        else{}   
}while(f < 15){
    winChance();
}

}
function winChance (){
array = [];
for (i=1;i<16;i++){
    array[i]= new Array();
    var currentId = $('#' + i).attr('id');
    var currentIn = $('#' + i).html()

    var currentIdNum = parseInt(currentId, 10);
    var currentInNum = parseInt(currentIn, 10);
    for (j=1;j<16;j++){
        var nextId = currentIdNum + j;
        if (nextId < 16){
            var nextIn = $('#' + nextId).html();
            var nextInNum = parseInt(nextIn, 10);
            if (currentInNum > nextInNum){
                array[i].push(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
checkSum();
}

function checkSum(){
var sum = 0; 
for (var a=1; a<16; a++){
    var add = array[a].length;
    sum = sum + add;
}            
var end = sum + 4;
if (end % 2 == 0){}            
else {       
    shuffle();
}            
}
```